# QML states does not work

Tags: qt, qml

Okay so here is the QML, what I want to do is that if an element is the current item that the box get big.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
width: 300; height: 200; color: "white"

ListModel {
    id: nameModel
    ListElement { name: "Alice"; }
    ListElement { name: "Bob";  }
    ListElement { name: "Jane"; }
    ListElement { name: "Harry";  }
    ListElement { name: "Wendy";  }
}

Component {
    id: nameDelegate
    Item {
        id: delegateItem
        width: parent.width
```

Here I try this:

```
states: [
            State {
                name: "current"
                when: ListView.isCurrentItem
                PropertyChanges { target: delegateItem; height: 44 }
            },
            State {
                name: "not"
                when: !ListView.isCurrentItem
                PropertyChanges { target: delegateItem; height: 26 }
            }]
        state: "not"

        Text {
            text: name
            font.pixelSize: parent.height - 4
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
```

Here I do something similair to verify if it works, it does work:

```
            color: delegateItem.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "black"
        }
    }
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: nameModel
    delegate: nameDelegate
    focus: true
    clip: true

    header: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width; height: 10;
        color: "#8080ff"
    }
    footer: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width; height: 10;
        color: "#8080ff"
    }
    highlight: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width; height: 10;
        color: "lightgray"
    }
}
}
```

Now I am wondering what is wrong, I know that `ListView.isCurrentItem` changes because 
I see that letters turn red when selected.

[image: See letters turn red, but box doesn't grow]

**EDIT**

The answer that jbh gave me was a good one. After which I changed `ListView.isCurrentItem` to `delegateItem.ListView.isCurrentItem` and it worked. This is because you can't access `isCurrentItem`  form the state, but if you go to `delegateItem` it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is directly linked with the definition of [Attached properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers).

An attached property, here `ListView.isCurrentItem`, is only available in the delegate component of your `ListView`. So it cannot work outside, and in your case, in the definition of a `State`